# How to center Android Listview items and add dynamic dividers to match the height of the Listview

Tags: android, listview, dynamic, divider

The idea is to add items to the center of the listview, and the divider between the items is of equal size and decreases if the number of items increses.

A rough sketch demonstrates what my question is about, how may i achieve this?

[image]

Comment: why don't you wrap your list view and keep its gravity center

Comment: it will stack the items together, i need to add dividers between items which take the remaining space on the screen

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need a ListView?

Maybe you can just add the items to a vertical LinearLayout and add `<Space>` views (with `layout_weight` between them.

Comment: and add that linear layout inside a scrollview in case if the collective size of the items exceeds the size of the screen?